# What are techniques to remove non-voice sounds (not "noise") from vocals

Tags: noise, vocals

I'm a new podcaster, and a first time audio editor - for 5 episodes I've been cutting and pasting using GoldWave and Audacity (to remove "noise.")

A recent recording session contains a lot of non-hiss background sounds, such as dishes clanking. Here's a short clip:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3838990/Sample.wav

There are so many controls on these editing applications that I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

If you really needed to get rid of them I would try Izotope RX3 spectral repair.  It can be extremely time consuming especially if your inexperienced with it.  The tough thing about dish sounds is they are in the same frequency range as the parts of the voices that you want to preserve.  It can save lots of time and money to get a good recording in off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend doing it the same way a dialogue editor would - manually edit them out, small crossfades in between.  Then try a noise supression tool after the fact as icing on the cake.  It's a great way to learn how to edit in practice.  Take dialogue for instance.  anyone editing voice must learn the intricacies of inflection, rhythm, and cadence - and furthermore, how to alter it in believable ways (hence, dialogue editors are called invisible artists - also why there's the saying "a seasoned dialogue editor is worth their weight in gold").  Unfortunately a catch-all like a plugin  for this siuation won't help all that much in my opinion and you frankly won't learn a whole from it.

Pushing a plugin button is limiting, a skill limited to the confines of a certain tool and its availability.  Learning to carefully and transparently edit sound however is a skill which you can carry on forever, regardless of the tool or medium, it transcends the tools, and put it to practice in many ways and constantly improve upon.

Good luck!